# Create a view in bigquery with date rounded down to midnight?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am creating a view in BigQuery with the following SQL statement:

`SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM [bucketname.tablename]`

How can I modify this query so that the `CreatedDate` becomes rounded down to midnight in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in BigQuery legacy SQL: try TIMESTAMP(DATE(CreatedDate))

as an example
CreatedDate = '2016-04-30 07:01:28 UTC'
DATE(CreatedDate) = '2016-04-30'
and finally TIMESTAMP(DATE(CreatedDate)) = '2016-04-30 00:00:00 UTC'

In mode of standart SQL: try [Format functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#format-functions)
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use the [`DATE` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions):

> Returns a human-readable string of a `TIMESTAMP` data type in the format `%Y-%m-%d`.

So:

```
SELECT Id, DATE(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate From [dataset.tablename]
```

Comment: I want the column to become a date column, so I think I need TIMESTAMP(DATE(CreatedDate))

Comment: @user1283776: Ah - that wasn't clear from your question. Glad you got an answer from Mikhail saying what you wanted to do.